# Digital sign From SHA1 to SHA256

Tags: c#, sign

I'm trying to update a function that performs a digital signature, I want to switch from SHA1 SHA256
 this is the current function:

```
private byte[] zSignData(Byte[] msg, X509Certificate2 signerCert)
{
    ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(msg);
    SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, false);
    CmsSigner cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(signerCert);

    cmsSigner.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("1.3.14.3.2.26"); //SHA1

    signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner, false);

    return signedCms.Encode();
}
```

this function work well

To update to SHA256, I changed

```
cmsSigner.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("1.3.14.3.2.26"); //SHA1
```

with

```
cmsSigner.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1");//SHA256
```

but at

```
signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner, false);
```

I get the following exception

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
>      Message=There was an internal error.

Someone has a suggestion?

I work with VS2010 Professional 64 and win7 professional 64

Comment: Is there an InnerException on the CryptographicException? Anything in the eventlog?

Comment: InnerException is null and no message in the eventlog

Answer (score 4):

i believe there is a typo bug in CAPIBase:

```
internal const string szOID_OIWSEC_SHA256 = "2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1";
internal const string szOID_OIWSEC_SHA384 = "2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2";
internal const string szOID_OIWSEC_SHA512 = "2.16.840.1.101.3.4.3";
```

should be:

```
internal const string szOID_OIWSEC_SHA256 = "2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1";
internal const string szOID_OIWSEC_SHA384 = "2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.2";
internal const string szOID_OIWSEC_SHA512 = "2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.3";
```

more discussion on this is here:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/217776fa-5dcd-41a6-a800-b401509fbbf0/#fbae9811-a5a2-418f-b049-dcbabf18431a
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/0cc90bdd-35f9-4a7d-8025-89f7ea9f9704/#deb21fba-1171-4eee-81ea-6de294abbeeb

blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2012/08/02/10018922.aspx

Todd, what makes you believe that OID 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 is not SHA256? What is the correct OID then?

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the wrong OID -that OID is for NULL signed blobs.  For an RSA signed blob, you need to use 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5 sha1RSA.

Comment: The error is the same. Microsoft has bungled with SHA256 with its libraries and its operating systems. I used Bouncy castle and I solved all problems